# How to make a directive independent from a module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The question might seem strange. But I like to organize my app in folder with directives being in a 'directives' folder, controller in a 'controllers' folder, etc....

In all the examples I've seen, directives are declared like that:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule').
directives('myDirective', function(){

});
```

What I want, is to declare myDirective in a separate file (which should not know about the app variable. 
Then when I create myModule, I'd like to assign it myDirective.

How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an app variable to define a directive, it is just a shortcut so you don't have to write `angular.module('myModule')` every time you want to define something in module. In your file with directive, simply define directive like this:

```
   angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective',function(){ ... });
```

And this directive will be part of `myModule`. Take a look how [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generates directives and controllers for more details. Or you can take a look at [Angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) application template which uses different approach, but the idea is the same.

Comment: That's not what I want because, in this case, I would have a reference to angular.module('myModule') into my directive file. Instead, I'd like to reference the directive in the file where my app module is declared. The only way I can think of, is to assign myDirective to its own module (just as you did) and then make that module a dependency of my app module. Is this the way to do it ?

Comment: just a follow-up, it seems to be how it's done in the angular seed project. So I guess I'll do it this way. :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all.

Answer (score 9):

The way I do this is to create a module of directives and then inject that into my app:

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app.directives', []).directive(...).directive(...)
```

**App**

```
angular.module('myApp',['app.directives'])
```

You can do the same for services, filters, etc...